# Variable declaration inside of class in Swift

Tags: swift, xctest

I'm new in swift automated testing with XCTest framework.
In my work I faced with correct arrangement some parts of code inside of test
Please explain the difference between variable declaration in the beginning of the class and in the certain function. Which way is preferred?

Var.1

```
class someClass: XCTestCase {
   let app = XCUIApplication()

   func someFunc {
       print (app.debugdescription)
   }
}
```

Var. 2

```
class someClass: XCTestCase { 

 func someFunc {
       let app = XCUIApplication()
       print (app.debugdescription)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable declaration as Class level or the Function level is same as in other programming languages, so it would be great if you understand their basic principle.

**Class level variable** means that this variable can be accessed throughout the class, that means it can be used in any function of the same class. It also means that if you make the class as public, and that variable as public, then once the class is initialized it could be accessed within your program in other classes. *Usually* they could create memory issues if you don't manage them properly as they stay in the memory when the class itself is within the memory.

**Function level variable** can only be accessed within that specific function and not outside that function whether it's the same class or a different class, they have no reference outside their function. *Usually* they don't create memory issues in your whole program as these variables leave the memory when that function is completely executed.

Answer (score 3):

**Var. 1** gives you the ability to configure your `XCUIApplication` in `setup()` and use it in the tests. Like this:

```
class someClass: XCTestCase {
   var app: XCUIApplication!

   func setUp {
      app = XCUIApplication()
      app.launchArguments.append("launchArgument")
      setupSnapshot(app)
      app.launch()
   }

   func test1 {
      XCTAssertNotNil(app)
   }

   func test2 {
      XCTAssertNotNil(app)
   }
}
```

With **Var. 2** you can setup your app differently in each test. Like this:

```
class someClass: XCTestCase {

   func test1 {          
      let app = XCUIApplication()
      app.launchArguments.append("withTestUser")
      app.launch()

      XCTAssertNotNil(app)
   }

   func test2 {          
      let app = XCUIApplication()
      app.launchArguments.append("withNoData")
      app.launch()

      XCTAssertNotNil(app)
   }
}
```

Comment: First example won't compile, since you declare `app` as a constant and then trying to change its value in `setUp`

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are possible but **var 2 is preferred**. For *var 1* solution consider the following scenario:

```
class State {
    var val: Int = 0
}

class TestClass: XCTestCase {
    let state = State()

    func test1() {
        state.val = 5

        XCTAssertEqual(5, state.val)
    }

    func test2() {
        XCTAssertEqual(0, state.val)
    } 
}
```

This way result depends on which test will run first. If `test2` will be the first then both tests will succeed. Other way, second test will fail.

For *var 2* solution

```
class TestClass: XCTestCase {
    func test1() {
        let state = State()            

        state.val = 5

        XCTAssertEqual(5, state.val)
    }

    func test2() {
        let state = State() 

        XCTAssertEqual(0, state.val)
    } 
}
```

both tests succeeds no matter what test will run firstly. This makes *var 2* solution preferred in most scenarios.

There is a case when *var 1* is more *convenient* than *var 2*. It is when SUT have many dependencies and you have to copy and paste creation code for them in each test. Then you can declare dependencies as a class variables, but you **must** use test `setUp` (and possibly a `tearDown`) to ensure that their states is refreshed before each test

```
class TestClass: XCTestCase {
    var dep1: Dependency1!
    var dep2: Dependency2!

    var sut: SUT!

    func setUp() {
        dep1 = Dependency1()
        dep2 = Dependency2()

        sut = SUT(dep1, dep2)
    }
}
```